# DC Motor's don't stop immediately

Tags: programming, c++, c

### Functionality

I have written this code below for a buggy to continue moving forward until there is an obstacle which is <= 25cm both motors should stop.

### Result

both motors stop when there is an obstacle which is <=25cm but the motors happen not to stop immediately when it comes across the obstacle please do find my code below is there something wrong with my code and how can I make it much better.

### Code

```
#define PING_PIN  12  // Arduino pin tied to both trigger and echo pins on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define PING_MAX_DISTANCE 200 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.

//initializing left DC Motor
const int in_1 = 2; // initializing the IN1 to Pin 2
const int in_2 = 3; //initializing the IN2 to Pin 3
const int EnA = 4;  //initializing pin 4 as pwm

////initializing Right DC Motor
const int in_3 =5;  // initializing the IN3 to Pin 5
const int in_4 = 6; // initializing the IN4 to Pin 6
const int EnB = 7;  //initializing pin 7 as pwm

// initialzing Ultrasonic sesor (Front view)
const int trigPin = 8;
const int echoPin = 9;

//For providing logic to L298 IC to choose the direction of the DC motor
void setup()
{
    /// initialize serial communication:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(EnA,OUTPUT);   //we have to set PWM pin as output
    pinMode(in_1,OUTPUT);  //Logic pins are also set as output
    pinMode(in_2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(EnB,OUTPUT);   //we have to set PWM pin as output
    pinMode(in_3,OUTPUT);  //Logic pins are also set as output
    pinMode(in_4,OUTPUT);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // Reading the signal from the sensor: a HIGH pulse
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);// set the trig pin to output (Send sound waves)
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);// set the echo pin to input (recieve sound waves)
    //pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);// set the trig pin to output (Send sound waves)
    //pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);// set the echo pin to input (recieve sound waves)
}


void loop()
{
    int duration, Distance; // start the scan
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2); // delays are required for a succesful sensor operation.
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); //this delay is required as well!
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    //---------------------------------------
    // convert the time into a distance
    //---------------------------------------
    Distance = (duration/2)/29.1;
    Serial.print(Distance);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
    if (Distance <= 25)
    {
        //Stopping Right and Left Motors
        digitalWrite(in_1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in_2,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in_3,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in_4,HIGH);
    }
    else {
        //Moving both Motors in a Foward motion - IN_1 = LOW , IN_2 = HIGH, IN_3 = LOW , IN_4 = HIGH
        digitalWrite(in_1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in_2,LOW);
        analogWrite(EnA,200); // Enablling the Right motor @ speed of 200
        digitalWrite(in_3,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in_4,LOW);
        analogWrite(EnB,200);// Enablling the Left motor @ speed of 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the motors stop immediately if you just disconnect them from the power?

Comment: Never use `delay()` on something that has to be responsive.

Comment: @MarkSmith yes they stop immediately when I disconnect them from the power

Comment: are you saying I shouldn't have delays for the ultrasonic sensor, and delay for displaying to the serial because those are the only place I used the delays in the program and I need the delays for a successful sensor operation  @EdgarBonet

Comment: delay(1000) is not directly responsive. Might want to move that to after the motor control?

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, your problem is in the use of `delay()`, which
*blocks* the program until the delay is over. When your program needs to
be responsive, you have to write everything in a *non-bloking* manner.
The basics of non-blocking management of time are covered in the
[Blink Without Delay Arduino
tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay), which I
strongly encourage you to read. Applying the technique of the tutorial
to your printing of the distance gives something like this:

```
static uint32_t last_time_printed;
uint32_t now = millis();
if (now - last_time_printed >= 1000) {
    Serial.println(Distance);
    last_time_printed = now;
}
```

I think the code is quite straightforward: you record the last time you
printed the value and, if it has been one second since last time, you
print it again.

You also have some other blocking calls in the section where you operate
the sonar. I would not worry too much about `delayMicroseconds()`: these
are really tiny delays, and your robot does not need to be *that*
responsive. I would worry about `pulseIn()` though: this function blocks
until it sees the end of the pulse, or until it reaches a timeout. The
default timeout is one second, which is way too large for this
application. Instead of relying on the default, you should specify a
timeout as a third parameter, as in

```
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH, 50000);  // timeout: 50 ms
```

This would limit the range to about 8 m, which I think should be
more than enough.

Reading the sonar pulse in a completely non-blocking fashion is
possible, by using either an input capture unit or an interrupt, but I
guess it is not worth the trouble, as your robot can probably cope well
with being blocked for 50 ms.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments have mentioned, the `delay(1000);` is probably doing you in. What's happening there is the code does absolutely nothing but count 1000ms for that time, so if the obstacle comes within 25cm during that delay, nothing will happen until the delay is done counting and the if statement occurs.

If you still want it to serial print every second, but not have that effect of slowing your response, try a counting variable (I forget the actual name). It's like a flag that you count on, so for example, you could have `int printCount = 0;` and instead of the delay(1000);, you'd have

`delay(1);
if(printCount > 999){
  Serial.println('Whatever');
  printCount = 0; //resets counter
} else{
  printCount++;
}`

Comment: make so much sense to me now thank you for your help I really appreciate it @Orotavia

Comment: Although this kind of works (albeit with very inconsistent timings), I don't think it's wise to encourage the OP to persist in using `delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

While I totally agree with the other answers on the issue of using a non-blocking timer, I would like to add another factor about motor braking from a purely "electrical" point of view.......

To "brake" a running DC motor, you need to short the two terminals. This will generate a back current in the coil which will reverse the magnetic field and stop the motor much faster than by just cutting off power to the terminals. This is not possible to implement using a Bi-polar H bridge motor driver like L293D. You need to use a MOSFET type H-bridge.

Comment: You _can_ break with a bipolar driver, if only through the free-wheeling diodes. This is even documented as “Fast motor stop” in the L293D datasheet.

Comment: @Edgar Could you provide a reference to this please? I can't find any mention of this in the [datasheet] (http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/1330.pdf)

Comment: See e.g. [table 3 of the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf#page=12).

Comment: I see the reference now, thanks. But this TI datasheet looks much more detailed than the one I linked to (SGS Thomson). I wonder why...